# Dualscreen not working when using a Dell XPS 15 via an HDMI cable to a TV

Tags: 11.10, screen, hdmi

I have a Dell XPS 15 and when i connect the hdmi cable to the TV absolutely nothing happens. Im running Ubuntu 11.10

EDIT:
I haven't installed any drivers and there are no ones in the "Additional Drivers"

And under Graphics in System info:

Driver: Unknown 
Experience: Standard

Comment: What drivers are you using (did you install any at all?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm answering my own question now, but after I have been trying to get hdmi to work with my computer for something like 10months now I just gave up.

My solution is to buy a "Mini Display Port" to "HDMI", and it works like a charm :D
Mini display port is a mac thing, but my computer has it and it works great :D got it for $35

Comment: Same problem of my XPS 15. I buyed a Mini Display Port to HDMI adapter and it works but with no audio.
Do you ear the computer audio on your TV?

Comment: Go the the sound settings and under hardware, look for HDMI profile in 'Settings for the selected device'