# Dell XPS L502Xnot detecting monitor-TV

Tags: 12.04, display

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Dell XPS L502X and when I connect the HDMI cable from the TV to the computer Ubuntu detects nothing at all, It works perfectly fine in Windows 7 though. I've already went to the Display control, plugged and unplugged the TV, clicked the Detect Displays button, and nothing. Do I have to activate the HDMI output or something? Because I used another computer with a VGA output and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Could you post the output of the `xrandr` command when the TV is connected over HDMI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 12.04 the Nvidia cards are not recognized in the display menu. You have to use Nvidia-Xserver-settings to do that.

Type Nvidia in the dash and open Nvidia-Xserver-settings.

Click on X server display configuration and then on detect displays. There you will find many more tweak options. Once ready click on apply and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact some model, i had this problem to, and i have tried everything you possibly can do and nothing works.

My workaround was to buy a mini-display to hdmi that looks like this[image]

Every Mac laptop's has this and i really don't know why Dell has it but it does and it works well, you should be able to get one at your computer store if not try [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/DisplayPort-Adapter-cable-Apple-Products/dp/B002ERBFYM/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1345391519&sr=8-1)

I asked this question earlier this year and this was my solution. You can find the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112260/dualscreen-not-working-when-using-a-dell-xps-15-via-an-hdmi-cable-to-a-tv)